# How to plot single intersecting point of 2 lines in Line Chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple line graph with two lines (line A and line B).  They
intersect at a given point (the break even point).  How do I indicate
on the graph that this is the break even point.  I know its very easy
to do with an arrow and text box.  However, I would like the arrow and
text box to move to a new intersection as I change the numbers around.

First tab "Break Even Analysis," is the sheet where I'm trying to highlight the "intersection point" of the yellow and blue lines of the break even:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bBkLnHCQnje6jXT_gUQPFO5AfBfs9WxdFwJAFsQX_cY/edit?usp=sharing

Essentially trying to dynamically plot the point circled in red as is shown in about minute 15 of this YouTube video for Excel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MxlVMzRxa8.

Answer (score -1):

I  am not sure what would be the ideal effect that you are after, but I wonder if you are familiar with the options built in Sheets UI. They allow dynamic visualization, custom charts and much more. There's also very handy Research tool. I pasted images  to NOTES sheet - docs are very different depending on the user, you may have some options disabled.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vxv8tc5Avi0iKlgmNvqMXyhxbCUiJSPP_nUkHCcX5ek/edit#gid=543398093

Comment: We like answers to be self-contained. When the link to your sample sheet stops working, there will be no useful information here; just an admonition to the Asker to read the help docs. Please consider adding the salient information to your answer and only use the sample document as supplemental information.